# Urdu writing in text box in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-vista, globalization, input-language

I am using following code to enable my text box to write in Urdu but it is typing in English as usual.  Please advise what do I need to make my textobx, take urdu as input

Thanks

```
Dim x As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ur-PK")
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(x)
```

Comment: +1, for using my native language. Urdu istimaal karne ke liye +1. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I added Urdu as a language option in Windows your code snippet started to work.

Comment: Please advise where to add this in Windows?

Comment: Windows 7: Control Panel -> Change keyboards or other input methods -> Change keyboards... -> Add... -> (select Urdu)

Comment: Thanks ! trouble is I have windows Vista Home, and I think we can not do this with Vista Home.................

Answer (score 0):

you should use this for better result
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(**1**)
for Urdu use 1, for different languages use 2,3,4 and so on
this work on textBox gotFocus event LIKE:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.GotFocus
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(1)
End Sub
```